# Unit testing: Required to mock methods of the class itself?

Tags: unit-testing

I've been doing some unit testing and just getting into the topic as a whole.

I stumbled upon the following scenario, suppose I have a class like this:

```
class A{
  public B mehtod_1(B b){
    b = method_2(b);
    b = method_3(b);
    b += 1; 
    return b;
  }

  public B method_2(B b){
    // do something to B without external dependency
    return B;
  }

  public B method_3(B b){
    // do something else to B without external dependency
    return B;
  }
}
```

I can write tests for `method_2` and `method_3` without a problem, do different tests by configuring B in different ways and asserting the expected transformation on B after the call, those methods are atomic.

So my question is:

If I was to test `method_1` in an atomic way I would have to mock the calls to `method_2` and `method_3` since if I would actually call these methods I would not test `method_1` in an atomic manor.

In the latter case is `method_2` was broken then the tests for `method_1` and `method_2` would break, and that would be misleading. If I'd mock the `method_2` call inside the `method_1` test, only the `method_2` test would fail, giving a clearer indication of where the error is (namely somewhere in the business logic of `method_1` given all other invoked methods worked as expected).

Did I understand the concept here correctly?

On the other hand it is correct, if both tests fail, since in the real world, `method_1` cannot work without `method_2` working.

My gut would say atomicity of tests is what is desired, meaning the first solution where there is one test for `method_1`, for every possible outcome of `method_2` and `method_3` (statically mocked).

Is there a "correct"/common/best practice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediate answer: in case we are talking Java here; and *partial mocking* is really of interest to you, you can look into using Mockito's [spy](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-spy-example/) concept.

But beyond that: you are getting unit testing wrong. What you call *atomicity*; I call **worrying about implementation details**. But it shouldn't matter "what exactly" that "method under test" actually does. You want to test the **what**, not the **how**.

Meaning: if that method has to call some other method(s) (that work fine in your unit test environment; without mocking); then there is no need thinking about mocking them!

You see: you care about the **contract** of each of your methods. That contract is what you want to test: *given* these input parameters, I *expect* that result/side effect/exception ...

Nonetheless, the fact that you have multiple **public** methods; and that they somehow depend on each other *might* be an indication of a design problem (as in: does it make sense that they are all public; is there some abstraction hiding in your interface that you should better express in other ways?). But that can only be decided given real code; real context.

Comment: I was actually using @Spy to partial mock these methods. It wasn't clear to me that unit tests were actually mean to only test the public interface of the methods / class. So if thats the case it doesn't make sense mock internal methods. And +1 for hinting that public methods probably should not depend on each other (apart maybe from methods that are wrapper, since Java doesn't support default parameters)